# JSON decode troubles, PHP

Tags: php, json, decode

I've already saw here lots of topics; but they are not very close to my situation. 
So I can't decode json with php (result is `NULL` and error is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`), here is this json: http://pastebin.com/7XUZB0Px

Json seems to be **valid**: 
I tried to validate it with http://json.parser.online.fr/ and with http://jsonlint.com/ and it's all ok; but however `json_decode()` doesn't work.

So my `php` try: http://codepad.org/DBxjihgE

Thx a lot for your help!

p.s. sry for lots of links - json is rather big, and example too.

**EDITED**

There was a comment (deleted now) to add a `stripslashes()`; this idea helped, have no idea why it works.

Comment: Is this your exact JSON or is it in another language? (reason I ask is cause of the '\u041a' parts in the json). Manual states: "This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.", could this be the issue?

Comment: That's odd. Try it with a smaler JSON and add more frome the original JSON until it don't work anymore. Then you know where the error is and maybe you can fix it then... That's how I would do it

Comment: thx a lot! There was a comment (deleted now) about `stripslashes()`, and that worked; dunno **why** it worked.
yes, originally I made this `json` from and array with function `json_encode()`, so It seems to me that there can not be encoding errors. But I'll try to check it.

Comment: Stripslashes will remove all slashes in the strings with russian characters. It might be a issue when trying to convert it back to russian characters.

Comment: Do you encode the object/array with any special OPTION set?

Comment: @Jite no, I used only `json_encode($arr)` without other params, but your idea about slashes seems to be correct.

Comment: You could try use the utf8_encode and utf8_decode functions before the json_encode, on the strings in russian that is.

Comment: The Answer is simple , Approach is wrong - when you <<<jsonvalues to $str , later var_dump($str); without jsondecode , you will understand that $str has a string and not json , that is the reason var_dump of json_decode(string) is ALWAYS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one you need to stripslashes()

```
$str = '<JSON STRING>';
$str = stripslashes($str);
$data = json_decode($str,true);

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` and `json_decode` requires the string to be UTF8 encoded.
It seems like you are using Russian letters in the json, it either get converted by the json_encode into a char sequence like `\u0414\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430` or you do it manually.
The JSON string wont be accepted by `json_decode` due to the slashes, you can, as others suggest, remove the slashes, but this will mess up the converted Russian characters.

If you escape the slashes on the strings that are russian, so instead of `\u0414` you get `\\u0414`, the json string will be accepted. This will though have to be done before converting the object into a json string with `json_encode`.

This should let you use json_decode on the string and get the correct values in the resulting array, with the Russian char sequence still "intact".

Comment: I tried to replace all the single slashes in the json string with double slashes, and it gives a more correct result, altho, I would not use that solution, cause it will add a escape slash on every slash in the string, which you might not want to escape!